# Using ProcessBatchData to apply permission on list items

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, permissions, 2016, batch

Can we use ProcessBatchData method of SPWeb to apply unique permission on a list item? I know this method supports insert/update/delete but I am not sure if we can apply permissions in bulk.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have look into the below third party tool :

Item Permission Batch

Bulk assign, remove or change SharePoint permissions

for multiple list items or documents.

This tool has free as well as paid version - if this is your one time use, you can download it and make use of this.

The above tool can be downloaded from [here](http://www.boostsolutions.com/batchpermission.html).

Comment: Yes I saw that but I want to do it from code as I am importing data in bulk from database into SharePoint list and want to assign permission on the fly.

Comment: Ohhk, I got it now :-)